# Reroganizar base de datros en mysql

Tags: mysql, genexus

```
GX18u8
.net Framework
mysql 5.7.4
```

Comienzo una kb sin problemas y hace el `create database` correctamente y su base de GAM. Cuando quiero agregar una trn y hacer `impact database` empiezan los fallos de este tipo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta configuración:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Termino ejecutando `ReorganizationScript.txt` a mano y no es la idea. Parece como si no pudiera generar el reorg.exe. Lo extraño es que anteriormente si logra hacerlo.

Comment: te da error en el path, no será un problema de permisos al estar en c directo,proba de darle permisos a la carpeta

Comment: No podría ser tema de permisos porque, como decía antes, el error da al comenzar la kb. Crea perfecto la BD de GAM y las tablas de las TRN. El problema surge luego del create database inicial